# Calling Mailgun from Python creates an unwanted broken-link graphic icon in email. Any way to avoid this?

Tags: python, outlook, mailgun

Sending an email through mailgun via the following python code causes the recipient to see an unwanted "broken-link" icon in ms-outlook (highlighted in YELLOW in the attached graphic). How can this be avoided?

[image: unwanted "icon" highlighted in yellow]

The code is as follows:

```
            def send_integration_notification_staging(sync_date, email_arg):
            ## sync_date is passed in as "2017-09-27"
            ## a valid email adddress is passed in to email_arg

                rptfn = runPath+"/rpt/post_processing_summary_" + sync_date + ".rpt"
                with open(rptfn, 'r') as rptfile:
                    rptcontent=rptfile.read()

                dfn1="student_rec_err_" + sync_date + ".csv"
                dfn2="parent_rec_err_" + sync_date + ".csv"
                dfn3="staff_rec_err_" + sync_date + ".csv"

                return requests.post(
                        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mystaging.mydomain.com/messages",
                        auth=("api", "key-<blah blah..values deleted>"),
                        files=[("attachment",(dfn1, open(runPath+'/rpt/'+dfn1, "r"))),
                                ("attachment",(dfn2, open(runPath+'/rpt/'+dfn2, "r"))),
                                ("attachment",(dfn3, open(runPath+'/rpt/'+dfn3, "r")))],
                        data={"from": "Administrator <admin@mydomain.com>",
                                "to": [email_arg],
                                "subject": "Integration Notification - Post Processing:  " + sync_date, "html": rptcontent})
```

And the example content of the file post_processing_summary_20170927.rpt:

```
            <head>
            <style>
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            Post processing report for 20170927:
            <p><p>
            <table>
            <tr><th>SyncDate</th>   <th>Status</th> <th>NumRecords</th></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STUDENTS - INVALID INFO</td>        <td>291</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STUDENTS - JOINING CENTRE/CLASS</td>        <td>55033</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STUDENTS - LEAVING CENTRE/CLASS</td>        <td>235</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STUDENTS - PENDING PROCESSING</td>  <td>2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STUDENTS - RECORD IN SYNC</td>      <td>8547</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>PARENTS - AMENDED INFO</td> <td>12060</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>PARENTS - INVALID INFO</td> <td>809</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>PARENTS - NEWLY ADDED</td>  <td>55643</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>PARENTS - RECORD IN SYNC</td>       <td>1387</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STAFF - INVALID INFO</td>   <td>373</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STAFF - JOINING CENTRE</td> <td>2604</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2017-09-27</td> <td>STAFF - RECORD IN SYNC</td> <td>1709</td></tr>
            </table>


            Please find attached the details of the various invalid Records
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is Mailgun's open tracking pixel and you should be able to confirm that by disabling it by going to your domain's settings.
[image: Mailgun domain tracking settings]

Unfortunately how email clients render is beyond Mailgun's control and you may need to decide how important open tracking is to you. You could also place a couple of `<br>`'s after `Please find attached the details of the various invalid Records` so it doesn't look quite *as* strange.